# Convergence in $L^{1}$ and integrability

Tags: measure-theory

Let $( X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $\{f_{n}\}$ be a measurable sequence of functions, and let $f$ also be measurable. In addition suppose $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and that: $$\int_{X} |f_{n} - f|d\mu \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty$$

Does it follow that $f_{n}$ and $f$ are integrable functions? i.e. that $f_{n} \in L^{1} (\mu)$, $\forall n$, and $f \in L^{1} (\mu)$?

I need this for a proof I am doing, but I cant for the life of me find a way to prove it.

Comment: No, it does not follow. Here is a counter-exemple. Consider $([0,1], \mathcal{B}, \mu)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Let $f$ be the function defined by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ if $x\in (0,1]$. Define for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, $f_n=\chi_{[0,\,1-\frac{1}{n}]}f$. Clealy $f$ is measurable, for all $n$, $f_n$ is measurable and $$\int_{[0,1]} |f_{n} - f|d\mu =\int_{[1-\frac{1}{n},1]} \frac{1}{x}d\mu \,\to 0 \;\;\;\text{ as } n \to \infty$$ However, for all $n$, $f_n \notin L^{1} (\mu)$ and $f\notin L^{1} (\mu)$.

Comment: @Ramiro: One can simplify your counterexample a bit by setting $f_n =f$ for all $n$.